# Parsing xml problem

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse this using PHP and simplexml_load_file but its not showing anything?

http://developer.multimap.com/API/geocode/1.2/OA10081917657704697?qs=Heaton&countryCode=GB

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

```
$results = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($results->Location() as $location) {
  foreach($location->Address() as $address) {
    foreach($address->Areas() as $areas) {
       foreach($areas->Area as $area) {
          echo $area->area;
       echo "<br />";
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Right after the `simplexml_load_file` call, put in `var_dump($results)` and show what's returned.  Also, have you checked your logs?  And set error_reporting to `E_ALL` to check for errors...

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
var_dump($xml);

That dumps everything back

Answer (score 1):

If you had [`error_reporting`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) enabled, you would see there is a

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::Location()
```

You are trying to access the elements with Method calls, e.g.

```
foreach($results->Location() as $location) {
```

when it should be

```
foreach($results->Location as $location) {
```

Same for the other elements.
Also, it's not `$area->area` but just `$area`.

Full fixed code:

```
$results = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($results->Location as $location) {
  foreach($location->Address as $address) {
    foreach($address->Areas as $areas) {
       foreach($areas->Area as $area) {
          echo $area;
       echo "<br />";
       }
     }
   }
}
```

On a sidenote, you can get all Area elements in the document without looping like crazy when using an XPath. However, since the elements are namespaced, you have to register that namespace with a prefix first to be able to use XPath:

```
$results = simplexml_load_file($url);
$results->registerXPathNamespace('d', 'http://clients.multimap.com/API');
$areas = $results->xpath('//d:Area');
foreach($areas as $area) {
    echo "$area<br/>";
}
```

Yet another way to get over all elements (though less performat than using an XPath) would be to use an Iterator to walk over the DOM Tree:

```
$elements = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    simplexml_load_file($url, 'SimpleXmlIterator'));
    
foreach($elements as $element) {
    if($element->getName() === 'Area') {
        echo $element;
    }
}
```